# Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.5.1.25624 - Or any other version

Tags: c#, asp.net, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization, webgrease

I have the same issue found in these questions

[Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.5.1.25624, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851912/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-webgrease-version-1-5-1-25624-culture-neutral)

[Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease' one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908895/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-webgrease-one-of-its-dependencies-the-located)

[Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180158/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-webgrease-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

None of the answers in these seem to help.

I have a **WebForms** project  Running .Net 4; **not** MVC.

I am adding bundling & minification using Microsoft Web Optimization, along with its dependencies.

I am receiving the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.5.1.25624, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have tried changing the version of web grease, and also web optimization. None are working.

These images show my current references, web config and other info:

Web Grease:
[image]

Web Optimization
[image]

Web Config
[image]

Packages Config
[image]

I am trying to apply my bundle by using the code below, in my master page:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/JS/Global") %>
    <%: System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/CSS/Global") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Anybody have any idea how I can get this working? I don't mind using an older version of the libraries; just can't seem to find one that isn't causing the issue.

Could it be the version of NewtonSoft.Json?

**Update**

So no matter what versions I install, I get the exact same message, right down to the version.. Can't seem to figure where the issue lays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you redirect `Newtonsoft.Json` version binding to version 7.0.0.0. There is no such version in your packages. Remove that redirection or add appropriate version of `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: That's what was already in the web.config - I'll give it a go and let you know.. :)

Comment: I just commented out that entire `<dependentAssembly>` node for Newtonsoft.Json and it worked. Thank you! - no idea why that was in there..