# Visual Studio 2013 Can't create new project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio Pro 2013 and all of a sudden I can't create a new project, I have tried repairing, uninstalling and installing nothing seems to fix my issue. Are are the error boxes I get when I try to create a new project:

[image]

[image]

They appear on that order. My question is how do I fix this?

Comment: I am going t guess that this only happens when trying to create a web application project?
seems like the problem is with the default configuration for a  web app project. Specifically the newtonsoft version?
 maybe this will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908895/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-webgrease-one-of-its-dependencies-the-located/22641629#22641629

Comment: Yes this problem does occur when trying to create a new project

Comment: Does it occur when creating any other type of project other than web(asp.net) project?